# Issue in using parameter in google map API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to implement google maps print for that i am using API

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=&daddr
```

To initiate print it is said to be that pw is the parameter . And i used like this

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Raleigh%20Road,%20Chapel%20Hill,%20NC,%20United%20States&daddr=Chapel%20Hill%20Road,%20Raleigh,%20NC,%20United%20States&dirflg=r&om=1&pw=2
```

But it is not showing any result but 404.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

That "API" is "classic" google maps. It was never documented officially and is no longer supported.

It has been replaced by the [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/)

Comment: In Embed API how can i search for routes at particular time ?